# Counterexample for "subsequence of a convergent sequence is convergent to same limit"

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let ${\{a_n}\}=\left\{\dfrac{1}{n}\right\}$ s.t. $n\in \mathbb{N}$, and let ${\{b_n}\}=\left\{{\dfrac{1}{n}}\right\}$ s.t. $n\in {\{1,...,N}\}$. How it is possible that ${\{b_n}\}$ is a subsequence of a convergent sequence ${\{a_n}\}$, but ${\{b_n}\}$ is convergent to $\dfrac{1}{N}$ and ${\{a_n}\}$ is convergent $0$?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How, $\{b_{n}\}$ convergences to $1/N$ ?

Comment: Because for ${\{b_n}\}={\{\dfrac{1}{n}}\}$, $n\in {\{1,...,N}\}$; I mean, $\dfrac{1}{N}$ is the last number of ${\{b_n}\}$.

Comment: How $b_{n}$ is a subsequence? $b_{n}$ is a finite set$\{1,1/2,...,1/N\}$ **NOT** a sequence

Comment: Sequence has **NO** last number

Comment: See definition of **Sequence** in any standerd book.

Comment: According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence (line 2), a sequence can have finite number of elements which is called "the length of the sequence".

Comment: For the purposes of calculus, a sequence is an infinite sequence. The word "infinite" is often left out.

Comment: Click on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#n-tuple.

Comment: Wikipedia says that, the sequence $\{(a_{n},b_{n})\}_{n}$ in $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$ is of length $2$ which is finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A real sequence is actually an injection $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$, while a subsequence of a sequence $\{f(n)\}_n$ is $f\circ\varphi:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$, where $\varphi:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ is a strictly increasing function, so that to form a subsequence we pick infinitely many elements of a sequence without disturbing their original order.

You can indeed consider finite sequences, but in the realm of analysis, so to speak, we are usually interested in what happens after finite "time" (that corresponds to considering the "tail" of a sequence). In this setting instead of finite sequences you can consider a sequence that is eventually constant, e.g. $\{1,1/2,1/3,...,1/N,1/N,1/N,...\}_n$. But in that case it is obvious that this sequence is not a subsequence of $\{1/n\}_n$.

Actually, in real analysis if you ever encounter a "finite sequence" $\{x_n\}_n$, chances are, that the image set $\{x_n|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is meant to be finite, but that does not mean that the occurences of terms, for which we have finitely many choices, are finite.